# Using google-apps-script, how do I grab the calendar name when going through events of a resource calendar?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've created a simply apps script to take in a resource calendar and list out the events in that resource and list out the attendees.  However, how do I get who's calendar is assigned to the event (not as a resource)?

For example:

- Team A Sync Up is the meeting invite name
- Bob is the calendar assignee (what shows up in the calendar field when looking at the details of a Google Calendar invite)
- May, John, Karen are the attendees
- Conference Room A is the resource

---

- Team B Sync Up is the meeting invite name
- Anna is the calendar assignee (what shows up in the calendar field when looking at the details of a Google Calendar invite)
- Kevin, Beth, Mark are the attendees
- Conference Room A is the resource

My script iterates through Conference Room A's calendar, and lists out the events

Team A Sync Up

May, John, Karen

---

Team B Sync Up

Kevin, Beth, Mark

What can I call to get the calendar assignee value?

`getName()` returns "Conference Room A" which is the name of the calendar I am iterating through instead of "Bob" or "Anna"

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.getOriginalCalendarId()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getOriginalCalendarId()) and [`.getCreators()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#getCreators()) methods might give you the information you need. It certainly gives the originator's calendar of an event.

This will cover for those events created by one person as delegated by another, it depends what your use case is for needing the information.

The underlying API for calendar (available as an advanced service) can give you organiser and creator as attributes.

Alternatively, you can cycle through the guest list and call the [`getGuestStatus()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/event-guest#getGuestStatus()) method and it can give you `OWNER` as one of the applicable values.

Comment: That's the twist though, the person creating the event isn't necessarily in the event.  So Emma could be creating an event "Team A Sync Up" and I still want "Bob" to be grabbed.  I'll give your suggestion a try though and see if that works

Comment: Use the latter then. Get the guest statuses. It might be you gave to get all 3 and use comparison logic for the result you need